# Trying to get a button to unhide pictures

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a button within my HTML to display images that are hidden when it is clicked.  I'm super new to working with jquery/js so any help that anyone would have is most appreciated.

Html for the input field and the button that should fire off the script:

```
<div class="col-md-3"> 
  <div>Select City</div>
  <input type="text" id="citySelector">
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="findHotel" data-dismiss="modal">Find Hotel</button>
```

Html for the images that would be displayed

```
<div class="container-fluid col-md-8 col-md-offset-3" id="chicagoResults">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="images/hotels/chicago/chicago1.png" id="chicagoHotels"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="images/hotels/chicago/chicago2.png" id="chicagoHotels"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#chicagoResults {
color: #f6f1ed;
margin-top: 110px;
margin-left: 180px;
display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
var citySelector = $("#citySelector").val().trim();

$("#findHotel").click(citySearch);
 function citySearch () {
  if (citySelector === "New York"){
   document.('nyResults').style.display = "block";
  }
 else if (citySelector === "Chicago"){
   document.('chicagoResults').style.display = "block";
 }
});
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue / question?

Comment: Are you asking for recommendations on how to improve your code or is your code not working at all?

Comment: @Billy code doesn't work at all at this point.  I'm not sure why, so any help getting it working or explaining why it doesn't work is useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to correct those lines :

```
document.('nyResults').style.display = "block";
document.('chicagoResults').style.display = "block";
```

By adding `getElementById` after `document.` :

```
document.getElementById('nyResults').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('chicagoResults').style.display = "block";
```

Also your function should end by `}` and not `});`, and you have to pass value of field to your function so add parameter to your function definition.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$("body").on('click', "#findHotel", function()
{
  citySearch($("#citySelector").val().trim());
});

function citySearch (citySelector) 
{
  if (citySelector === "New York")
      $('#nyResults').show();
  else if (citySelector === "Chicago")
      $('#chicagoResults').show();
}
```

```css
#chicagoResults, #nyResults {
  color: #f6f1ed;
  margin-top: 110px;
  margin-left: 180px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3"> 
  <div>Select City</div>
  <input type="text" id="citySelector">
  <button type="button" id="findHotel">find Hotel</button>
</div>
    
<div class="container-fluid col-md-8 col-md-offset-3" id="chicagoResults">
<table>
  
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://foto.hrsstatic.com/fotos/3/3/256/256/80/FFFFFF/http%3A%2F%2Ffoto-origin.hrsstatic.com%2Ffoto%2F0%2F0%2F0%2F2%2F000279%2F000279_a_3979595.jpg/Tw1WKUCVIFelYvywT6gzeQ%3D%3D/259,140/6/WYNDHAM_GRAND_CHICAGO_RIVERFRO-Chicago-Exterior_view-3-279.jpg" id="chicagoHotels"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid col-md-8 col-md-offset-3" id="nyResults">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://foto.hrsstatic.com/fotos/0/3/256/256/80/000000/http%3A%2F%2Ffoto-origin.hrsstatic.com%2Ffoto%2F5%2F4%2F7%2F5%2F547591%2F547591_z_4564886.jpg/jJ7hmPcA3%2F9wQG%2BKfy0p8g%3D%3D/560,373/6/RADISSON_BLU_AQUA_CHICAGO-Chicago-Room-21-547591.jpg" id="chicagoHotels"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing this:

```
document.('nyResults').style.display = "block";
document.('chicagoResults').style.display = "block";
```

to this:

```
$('#nyResults').show();
$('#chicagoResults').show();
```

Final Code:

```
$("#findHotel").click(function() {
  var citySelector = $("#citySelector").val().trim();
  if (citySelector === "New York"){
    $('#nyResults').show();
  } else if (citySelector === "Chicago"){
    $('#chicagoResults').show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend learning the basics of javascript itself before diving into a library.

That being said, (despite the syntax errors) there are a couple problems with your code:

---

**Your click event defines a function, but never calls it.**

You need to call a function for the code inside of it to be executed.

---

**You're using a Table to hold your layout.**

A `<Table>` tag used for presentation purposes is the scourge of good web design. Use divs and style them as tables if need be with `display: table` and `display: table-cell` but do not use the `<Table>` tag unless you're filling it with tabular data.

```js
$(function(){
  var findButton = $("#find-button");
  var chicagoResults = $("#chicagoResults");

  findButton.on("click", function(){
      var input = $("#city-selector").val().trim().toLowerCase();

      if(input === "chicago"){
          chicagoResults.css({display: "block"});
      }
      else if(input === "new york"){
          //show new york block
      }
  });
});
```

```css
#chicagoResults {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3"> 
  <div>Select City</div>
  <input type="text" id="city-selector">
</div>
    
<button id="find-button">FindHotel</button>
    
    
    
<div class="container-fluid col-md-8 col-md-offset-3" id="chicagoResults">
    <p>yay</p>
</div>
```